# How to read null values out of a integer column in sql to C#?

Tags: c#, sql, null

i am trying to make a project for my school. I am trying to read a table where some null values are in an integer column. I've made it an integer but i can't get the null values into the integer.

I've already searched in stackoverflow but none of the answers i could make at my project. Can someone provide me some help, tell me where i have to put the code to make it work again. I just started as programmer.

This is my database conn string + reader:

```
        public static List<Klant> GetAlleklanten()
        {
            var result = new List<Klant>();
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                const string query = "select k.klantid, k.naam, k.adres, k.telefoonnummer, k.woonplaats, k.email, k.wachtwoord, kp.klantpasid from klant k left join klantpas kp on k.klantid = kp.klantid";
                SqlCommand selectKamers = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                SqlDataReader reader = selectKamers.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Klant klant = new Klant((int)reader["klantid"], (string)reader["naam"], (string)reader["adres"], (string)reader["telefoonnummer"], (string)reader["woonplaats"], (string)reader["email"], (string)reader["wachtwoord"], (int)reader["klantpasid"]);
                    result.Add(klant);
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

`klantpasid` is the one that also can return a null value instead of an integer. 
Here is the class where the klantpasid is in the construtor:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FontysHotel
{
    public class Klant
    {
            // instantie variabelen
            private int klantid;
            private string naam;
            private string adres;
            private string telefoonnummer;
            private string woonplaats;
            private string email;
            private string wachtwoord;
            private int? klantpasid;

            // properties
            public int Klantid
            {
                get
                {
                    return klantid;
                }
                set
                {
                    klantid = value;
                }
            }

            public string Naam
            {
                get
                {
                    return naam;
                }
                set
                {
                    naam = value;
                }
            }
            public string Adres
            {
                get
                {
                    return adres;
                }
                set
                {
                    adres = value;
                }
            }
            public string Telefoonnummer
            {
                get
                {
                return telefoonnummer;
                }
                set
                {
                telefoonnummer = value;
                }
            }
            public string Woonplaats
            {
                get
                {
                    return woonplaats;
                }
                set
                {
                    woonplaats = value;
                }
            }
            public string Email
             {

                get
                {
                    return email;
                }
                set
                {
                    email = value;
                }
            }
            public string Wachtwoord
            {
                get
                {
                    return wachtwoord;
                }
                set
                {
                    wachtwoord = value;
                }
            }

            public int? Klantpasid
            {
                get
                {
                    return klantpasid;
                }
                set
                {
                    klantpasid = value;

                }
            }
            // Constructor
            public Klant(int klantid, string naam, string adres, string telefoonnummer, string woonplaats, string email, string wachtwoord, int klantpasid)
            {
                Klantid = klantid;
                Naam = naam;
                Adres = adres;
                Telefoonnummer = telefoonnummer;
                Woonplaats = woonplaats;
                Email = email;
                Wachtwoord = wachtwoord;
                Klantpasid = klantpasid;
            }
     }
}
```

Please provide me some help, tell me where i have to place the right code so i can continue my school project. The error i am getting now is ''' The specified conversion is invalid
'''

Comment: `reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("klantid")) ? -1 : Conver.ToInt32(reader["klantid"])`

Comment: Not exactly sure what you meant ... 1) Is it (maybe) wrong, that Klantid has null values in your database? If it is your primary key, i guess it should be a unique value, NULL values wont help here. If so, you'll need to correct your data in your database: assign them values. 2) If it is correct, that your Klantid can be NULL, then you need to adapt your C# code to it - make Klantid a Nullable: `public int? Klantid` and `private int? klantid;`

Answer (score 2):

You can check `klantid` for `DBNull.Value`, and if it is, assign corresponding special `int` value; so instead of

```
(int)reader["klantid"]
```

put

```
reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("klantid")) ? -1 : Conver.ToInt32(reader["klantid"])
```

a better way is to declare `private int klantid;` as `private int? klantid;` (nullable `int`):

```
private int? klantid; // it can accept null now

public int? Klantid
{
    get
    {
        return klantid;
    }
    set
    {
        klantid = value;
    }
}
```

then while reading from `reader` we can use turnary operator:

```
KlantId = !reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("klantid")) 
  ? Conver.ToInt32(reader["klantid"])
  : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know a fix for you,
You change Klantpasid from int? to int
If klantpasid is null in your database, we set the value to 0 instead of null

```cs
            public int Klantpasid
            {
                get
                {
                    return klantpasid;
                }
                set
                {
                if( value == null){
                  klantpasid = 0;
                  }else {
                    klantpasid = value;

                  }

                }
            }
```

Comment: This does not work, the result of the if statements is always false because an integer can't be null

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your property as nullable

```
public int? Klantid
{
    get
    {
        return klantid;
    }
    set
    {
        klantid = value;
     }
}
```

Check out more on [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/).

Answer (score 0):

When you read your data with a `DataReader`, it will return `DBNull.Value`. Whe you want to fill your `Klant.Klantpasid` value (which is of type `Nullable<int>`), you will have to convert the value to `Nullable<int>` yourself. When ADO.NET was first implemented, there were no nullable values, so they introduced `DBNull` instead. More modern approaches like Entity Framework use nullable types instead.

You can write a helper method to help converting your read value to a nullable type:

```
static T? AsNullable<T>(object value) where T : struct {
    switch (value) {
        case T converted:
            return converted;
        case DBNull:
            return default(T?);
        default:
            throw new InvalidCastException();
    }
}
```

So instead of...

```
(int)reader["klantpasid"]
```

...you write:

```
AsNullable<int>(reader["klantpasid"])
```

And of course you change the type of your constructor parameter from `int` to `int?`.